# Is there a way to have cardinality on the top and bottom of a relationship?

Tags: cardinality, dia

By default it seems you can only have cardinality displayed on the left and right sides of the Relationship shape.

With that kind of behaviour it makes it a bit confusing to understand which is which when I put the entities on the top and bottom of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the Relationship properties, set rotate to yes. Then you can specify left and right cardinality and it will automatically appear in the top and bottom. Rotating the relationship does the trick.